# SQL query one to many relationship join without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I'm running queries in SQL Server 2008.. I have a `sales` table and a `payments` table.. sometimes a sale has multiple methods of payment (part giftcard + part cash or part credit + part cash etc..) so what I want to do is list the sales and the payments for each sale in a table.

If I do a `LEFT JOIN ON sales.SaleID = payments.SaleID` I get duplicate sales rows when there are more than one matching payment rows..

So what I have been doing is getting all the sales and a count of how many matching payment rows there are with `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments WHERE payments.SaleID = sales.SaleID) AS NumOfPayments`. Then in my PHP script I check the number of payments and if it is `> 1` I then run another query to get the payment details.

The output I am trying to get would look something like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| SaleID |  SaleDate  | Amount  | Payments          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    123 | 2013-07-23 | $ 19.99 | Cash:     $ 19.99 |
|    124 | 2013-07-23 | $  7.53 | Cash:     $  7.53 |
|    125 | 2013-07-23 | $174.30 | Credit:   $124.30 |
|        |            |         | GiftCard: $ 50.00 |
|    126 | 2013-07-23 | $ 79.99 | Cash:     $ 79.99 |
|    127 | 2013-07-23 | $100.00 | Credit:   $ 90.00 |
|        |            |         | Cash:     $ 10.00 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Where sale 125 and 127 have multiple payments listed but the sale information only appears once and is not duplicated for each payment.

The `sales` and `payments` tables look like this:

```
Sales                              Payments
---------------------------------  --------------------------------------------
| SaleID |  SaleDate  | Amount  |  | PaymentID | SaleID | PmtMethod |  PmtAmt |
---------------------------------  --------------------------------------------
|    123 | 2013-07-23 | $ 19.99 |  |       158 |    123 |        4  | $ 19.99 |
|    124 | 2013-07-23 | $  7.53 |  |       159 |    124 |        4  | $  7.53 |
|    125 | 2013-07-23 | $174.30 |  |       160 |    125 |        2  | $124.30 |
|    126 | 2013-07-23 | $ 79.99 |  |       161 |    125 |        3  | $ 50.00 |
|    127 | 2013-07-23 | $100.00 |  |       162 |    126 |        4  | $ 79.99 |
---------------------------------  |       163 |    127 |        2  | $ 90.00 |
                                   |       164 |    127 |        4  | $ 10.00 |
                                   --------------------------------------------
```

I feel like if I can do it with just SQL it will be faster. Is there a way to accomplish this with pure SQL instead of having to use server side code to run conditional queries.

Comment: All sales will have atleast one record in payments table, correct?

Comment: @VasanthSundaralingam Yes each sale should have at least one corresponding payment record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mix data retrieval and data display, which is what I think you are asking about.  Do you have some sort of column to indicate which payment should be displayed first?  I'm thinking something like:

```
SELECT columnlist, 
rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sales.salesID ORDER BY payment.paymentID)
FROM sales JOIN payments ON sales.salesID=payments.salesID
```

Then, in your GUI, just display the values for the first 3 columns where RN = 1, and blank out the values where RN > 1.

Comment: I've tred this approach using mysql 5.6 and it's giving me the amazingly concrete message "You have an error in your SQL syntax" :(

Comment: MySQL ain't SQL Server :)  I don't think that MySQL supports the ROW_NUMBER() functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to do this in the interface.

The basic query you want is:

```
  select s.saleID, s.SaleDate, s.Amount,
         p.PaymentType, p.PaymentAmount,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.SaleId order by p.PaymentAmount desc) as seqnum
  from sales s join
       payments p
       on p.saleID = s.saleId
  order by 1, 2
```

However, you are trying to blank-out fields.  To do this, you need to convert all the fields to strings and then check if which are on the first line for each `SaleId`:

```
select (case when seqnum > 1 then '' else CAST(SaleId as varchar(255)) end) as SaleId,
       (case when seqnum > 1 then '' else CONVERT(varchar(10), SaleDate, 121) end) as SaleDate,
       (case when seqnum > 1 then '' else '$'+STR(amount, 6, 2) end) as Amount,
       PaymentType, PaymentAmount
from (select s.saleID, s.SaleDate, s.Amount,
             p.PaymentType, p.PaymentAmount,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.SaleId order by p.PaymentAmount desc) as seqnum
      from sales s join
           payments p
           on p.saleID = s.saleId
     ) sp
order by SaleId, SaleDate;
```

This is not the type of operation that SQL is designed for.  SQL works with tables, where all columns have the same meaning.  Here, you are introducing a different meaning for the column, depending on its position in the sale.  Yes, SQL can do it.  No, it is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give the results you need, you need to skip the SalesIDToSort column.

```
  ;with SalesData
  as
  (
    select 
      Sales.SalesID, Sales.SalesDate, Sales.TotalAmount, Payments.PaymentMode, Payments.Amount,
      Row_Number() over(Partition by Sales.SalesID order by Payments.PaymentID) RowNum
    from 
      Payments
      inner join Sales on Payments.SalesID = Sales.SalesID
  )
  select SalesID, SalesDate, TotalAmount, PaymentMode, Amount, SalesID SalesIDToSort
  from 
    SalesData
  where
    SalesData.RowNum = 1
  union all
  select null, null, null, PaymentMode, Amount, SalesID SalesIDToSort
  from 
    SalesData
  where
    SalesData.RowNum > 1
  order by 6
```

[Working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a461d/6)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a gourp by function such as Format to:

```
select salesid, salesDate, Amount, FORMAT(payment, 9999.999) as payments
from FROM payments 
WHERE payments.SaleID = sales.SaleID
group by salesid;
```

this might work if you have FORMAT as an available function.