# How to query One-to-Many entities?

Tags: php, mysql

In my system (PHP/MySql) I have a **User** table and **Images** table.
One User can have many Images.

I have a page where a need to list all Users(even if the user don't have Images) and all Images, for each user.
How can I get this?

Solution 1

> ```
>  $users = query('SELECT * FROM Users')
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
>  foreach($users as $user)  
>      $user->images = query('SELECT id, path, size FROM Images WHERE user_id = ' . $user->id)
> ```

Solution 2

> $users = query('SELECT *, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id,path,size) FROM Images) as images FROM Users')
>
> then
>
> ```
>  foreach($users as $user)
>
>    list($id,$path, $size) = explode(',', $user->images)
>    $user['images'] = ['id' => $id, 'path' => $path, 'size' => $size];
> ```

There is a better way to acomplish this?

P.S. 1: Using LEFT JOIN duplicate the results.

P.S. 2: Using INNER JOIN / JOIN , Users that don't have Images are ignored.

Comment: use inner join, why dont you use ?

Comment: Cause it wil ignore Users that dont have Images. Right?

Comment: Inner join will ignore the user whihc doesnot have records in image table right???

Comment: see updated post, and the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769641/left-join-without-duplicate-rows-from-left-table

Answer (score 0):

Here, the example (Remember Inner join is the Intersection of both table)

```
SELECT
Users.id as user_id,
Images.id as image_id,
Images.path,
Images.size
FROM
Users
INNER JOIN Images ON Users.id = Images.user_id
```

IF you want to use INNER JOIN, But remember for large and many data, JOINs are slower and not recommended. Learn how to get data when you need, I recommend define REST endpoints and make ajax requests and get data when your web client need.
If you dont want to miss any user and also dont want duplicate then see following links.

**Update:**
I see your updated post. this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410622/prevent-duplicate-values-in-left-join) will help you.

and more precisely the answer here [Left Join Without Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769641/left-join-without-duplicate-rows-from-left-table)

and [Two tables, whit one to many relationship. How to join values without duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695199/two-tables-whit-one-to-many-relationship-how-to-join-values-without-duplicate)

Comment: Thanks for the link! But using the query in the link results in only one image(I think it's the first found).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818703/sql-query-one-to-many-relationship-join-without-duplicates

Comment: you can find solution by concatinating all the image's id to a field and left join here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695199/two-tables-whit-one-to-many-relationship-how-to-join-values-without-duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User.* Images.id as images_id, path, size
FROM Images
LEFT JOIN on User user.id = Images.user_id
```

Comment: With this I've got good results, but then I have to select * from users, and then mix the results?

Comment: you dont have mix the results, you can select other (or all) columns from User, I will edit post

Comment: Right. So to query for information about the User I query the Images table. Cool. But if User have another one-to-many? Like Groups? I'll query Images table or Groups Table?

Comment: SELECT User.* Images.id as images_id, path, size      use this for select and you will have everyting

Comment: in that case User is betwen those two tables and its like relationships like many to many, Images and grup trough Users have many to many relationship

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15634614)

Answer (score 0):

Here is all posibility query on 2 table, students and payment.

```
Tables:   students                payment
    id_student  name        id  id_student datepayment
    1         Lisa         1    1        2017-01-01
    2                      2    1        2017-02-03
    3         Asher        3    2        2017-03-05
    4         Lee          4    1        2017-03-03
```

This query:

```
select students.name, payment.datepayment
FROM students, payment
where students.id_student = payment.id_student;
```

will give this result - all student's name which has id_student in table payment

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
Lisa    2017-03-03
        2017-03-05
```

This query:

```
SELECT s.name, p.datepayment
FROM
students s
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment p ON s.id_student = p.id_student;
```

will give this result: all student's name from LEFT table (students) which has or has not id_student in table payment

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
        2017-03-05
Lisa    2017-03-03
Asher       NULL
Lee         NULL
```

This query:

```
SELECT s.name, p.datepayment
FROM
students s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN payment p ON s.id_student = p.id_student;
```

will give this result - all from RIGHT table payment and only student's name which has id_student in table payment

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
        2017-03-05
Lisa    2017-03-03
```

This query:

```
SELECT s.name, p.datepayment
FROM
students s
INNER JOIN payment p ON s.id_student = p.id_student;
```

will give this result - all student's name which has id_student in table payment

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
Lisa    2017-03-03
```